# Power Automate: Send eMail mit Sharepoint attachement

Tags: power-automate

I have a problem creating a flow. All files for the flow are in a sharepoint. In an Excel list, I call up various information such as name, surname, e-mail and also the file name of the e-mail attachment. The e-mail attachment is also stored on the Sharepoint in a different underlying folder. How do I include the attachment in the flow?

The whole flow works fine. However, when I let the attach file be selected dynamically like,

[image]

the flow runs into an error:

[image]

Without a dynamic attachment (hard coded) it runs through without error:

[image]

Here the eMail result - hard coded attachement:

[image]

Any idea how to select the attachment dynamicaly?
Thank you very much for your help.

Kind regards
Andi

Comment: You made my day! Thank you very much for the hint. I'm able to fix "my" issue :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use this specific action ...

[image: Action]

... there are two and the one I have shown is the one you'll need to use.